# Semantic Error whith Symfony annotation and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, annotations

I need to add a column to a database with Doctrine migration but the console returns me that:

> [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
>     [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\progetto_id" in property Bs\PlutoBundle\Entity\ProgettoPaesiOCM::$progetto_id does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

The code is:

```
<?php

namespace Bs\PlutoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * PaesiOCM
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="progetto_paesiocm")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class ProgettoPaesiOCM
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="progetto_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\progetto_id
     */
    protected $progetto_id;


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="paesiocm_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Column paesiocm_id
     */
    protected $paesiocm_id;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Get progetto_id
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProgettoId()
    {
        return $this->progetto_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set progetto_id
     *
     * @param int $progetto
     * @return ProgettoPaesiOCM
     */
    public function setProgettoId($progetto)
    {
        $this->progetto_id = $progetto;

        return $this;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    /**
     * Get paesiocm_id
     * @return int
     */
    public function getPaesiOcmId()
    {
        return $this->paesiocm_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set paesiocm_id
     *
     * @param int $paesi
     * @return ProgettoPaesiOCM
     */
    public function setPaesiOcmId($paesi)
    {
        $this->paesiocm_id = $paesi;

        return $this;
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->progettoPaesiOCM = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing this line :  * @ORM\Column paesiocm_id

Comment: I have try as you can suggest and now I have a new error

Comment: [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
  The table with name 'psbsnstr_pluto.progetto_paesiocm' already exists.

Comment: I want add a column in another table but when launch the command the error is to ProgettoPaesiOCM table why?

Comment: Maybe add the structure of your database table to this post ?

Comment: What did you try to achieve with the `@ORM\progetto_id` part? That line should be removed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should delete this line

```
 * @ORM\progetto_id
```

And this line

```
 * @ORM\Column paesiocm_id
```